# Encoding OGG vorbis as CBR?

Tags: encoding

I'd like to use OGG@64kbps as an output format (for low data consumption). I'm currently writing an audio streaming client, and I need the estimated data size before streaming. It would be great if the prediction could be accurate to within a few kB. Is it possible to set up ffmpeg or SoX to encode into Ogg/CBR so I can calculate the exact data size?

I agree VBR would be the better option where quality is concerned, but VBR 64kbps doesn't mean that I actually get 64kbps in average. Sadly...

Or would ABR be an option?

Thank you!

Comment: Opus has a "hard-cbr" option, which acts as true CBR. You can be sure that the bit rate can estimate the size of the overall file.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using CELT or Opus for low bitrate audio (48kbps-96kbps), it [sounds far superior](http://listening-tests.hydrogenaud.io/igorc/results.html), even compared to high performance ACC-HE+. the later is an IETF standard, and already widely supported.

Both support CBR, ABR (CVBR), VBR.

Vorbis supports VBR, ABR.

ffmpeg documentation for [Vorbis](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libvorbis) and [Opus](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libopus-1) have easily defined options for ABR control.

Answer (score 0):

Ogg is a VBR codec.
but as you seem to know you still can setup a certain bitrate.

Here is what I found on the [net](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1847088)

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -i hw:0,0 -acodec libvorbis -aq 4 -vn audio.ogg
```